# "convert to" is not there in my blender 2.8 version

Tags: text-object

In my blender 2.8 version the "convert to", which is present in Search option is not there.  What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're in Object Mode with an object selected, otherwise the 'Convert To' option won't appear in the search.

Otherwise, in Object Mode with an object selected, you can find the option in the Object menu.

[image]

Comment: Also available by pressing W if Right Click Select, or through right-clicking the object if Left Click Select.

Comment: I don't see it in the context menu in Blender 2.8 either.

Comment: it's still not there in object mode.